# Remove observable action is subscription is unsubscribed

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, ngondestroy

I have a problem which I tought I can solve with a subscription:

```
refresh$: Subscription;
data$: Subscription;

ngOnInit() {
  this.refresh = interval(1000).subscribe(() => {
      this.getData();
    }
  );
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.refresh$.unsubscribe();
  this.data$.unsubscribe();
}

getData() {
  this.data$ = service.getData().subscribe(response => {
    // here, based on response, I update the header component value whithin an event
  }, err => {
    // also, if catch error, update header component
  }); 
}
```

Because I have an interval at 1 seconds and the server is down (intentional), my interval will emit 5 requests in 5 seconds, but the answer foreach will came in much time as 1 second.

So, when I emit first request and wait its answer (which will throw an error), already will emit the second request, the thirs, and so on.

In this time, if I leave the page (calling `ngOnDestroy`), I want to update the header from another component. But, after leaving the page, I will receive all the responses (success or failure) of the previous component. I want to cancell all these when I leave it. I thought that `unsubscribing` to `data$` will solve this, but the problem persist.

thanks

Comment: It seems that `$data` has the last subscription so.. Is it possible that the previous ones are still alive waiting to handle the results? If that's the case you may need to save an array of subscriptions or design another implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have nested subscriptions which is bad practice and makes it harder to unsubscribe from all inner subscriptions. Use an observable mapping operator like `mergeMap`, `switchMap`, `concatMap` or `exhaustMap` to map to an inner observable and use `takeUntil` to unsubscribe.

```ts
private destroy$ = new Subject();

ngOnInit() {
  interval(1000).pipe(
    concatMap(() => this.getData()),
    takeUntil(this.destroy$)
  ).subscribe(response => {
    // update the header component value based on response
  });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.destroy$.next();
  this.destroy$.complete();
}

getData(): Observable<any> {
  return service.getData().pipe(
    catchError(error => {
      // update header component on error
      return EMPTY; // if the subscribe callback shouldn't be executed on errors

      // OR return an observable with the value the subscribe callback in ngOnInit should receive
      return of(/* what the header should be set to on errors */)
    })
  ); 
}
```

You could also use the `async` pipe to subscribe and handle the subscription. Maybe use `timer` instead of `interval` to send the first request without an initial delay.

```ts
data$ = timer(0, 1000).pipe(
  concatMap(() => this.getData()),
);

getData(): Observable<any> {
  return service.getData().pipe(
    catchError(error => {
      return of(/* what the header should be set to on errors */)
    })
  ); 
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ng-container *ngIf="data$ | async as data">
    {{ data }}
  </ng-container>
</header>
```

Comment: thanks, using pipe() on interval() is awesome. I can not use async pipe in template because I have a huge logic inside of subscribe()

Answer (score 0):

I found a quickly solution, but is not the best, because this don't close the subscription.

declare a boolean `pageLeaved = false` and set it true on `ngOnDestroy`. then, in error case of subscription, just return if the `pageLeaved` is true.

```
pageLeaved = false;
refresh$: Subscription;
data$: Subscription;

ngOnInit() {
  this.refresh = interval(1000).subscribe(
      () => {
        this.getData();
      }
    );
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.pageLeaved = true;
  this.refresh$.unsubscribe();
  this.data$.unsubscribe();
}

getData() {
  this.data$ = service.getData().subscribe(response => {
    // here, based on response, I update the header component value whithin an event
  }, err => {
    // also, if catch error, update header component
    if (this.pageLeaved) {
       return;
    }
  }); 
}
```

Please note that this is "just a momentary solution", because the error case will be called even if the observable is unsubscribed. If you have a better example,feel free to answer.